# MC Win 10 beta mob trap not working

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I started a SkyBlock on MineCraft Windows 10 edition and built a mob trap. It is just a basic canal design, but for some reason, it is not working properly. it sometimes works slowly when I'm far away from it, but when I'm standing right by it, it won't work at all. I've tried making it 24-45 blocks high.

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with It? I really need some bones.
[image: right outside][image: Inside]

Comment: I am not familiar with Win10 edition, so here are just some things I'd check from my Java edition experience: 1) make sure all spawning floors are between 24 and 32 meters from your position. Mobs don't spawn closer than 24 and don't move farther than 32. 2) make sure mobs are not afraid of ledges (mobs won't jump off a 3 meter ledge, line the canals with trapdoors open downwards, as those seem walkable to mobs)

Comment: I checked the room when it was at 24 and 30 but no mobs were spawning in there at all so it's not a problem with the ledge

Comment: I'm pretty sure that mob spawning works differently between the PC and Pocket editions... Correct me if I'm wrong, but it's very similar to how spawning worked in Alpha.

Comment: I didn't play the alpha so I don't know how spawning worked in the alpha

Comment: @aytimothy What do you mean by Alpha behavior? If you mean the "bailout clause", then SkyBlock environment is actually ideal for that algorithm. Even with 0,0 chunk sorting bug SkyBlock won't be affected. As far as I can see from the wiki and several forum threads, nothing has changed regarding 24 meter sphere and light level.

Comment: @ConstantCanadian can you please attach more pictures of your spawner? For example, what does it look like from outside, and where is the place you usually stand on while waiting.

Comment: @OrcJMR Mob spawns as the chunks are loaded, similar to how it was back in Minecraft Alpha, meaning to get more mobs, you **must** move around, as opposed to mobs spawning in and out while you stay still around you ([see answer below](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/235451/75275)). It's only until *Minecraft Beta* where mob grinders (the big dark room ones) work.

Comment: @aytimothy Hmmm... I've skimmed over several videos on Youtube where people build standard water canal above ground spawners in PE... And they all either don't show any mobs coming out, or use spawner blocks, or show empty grinder and then just cut to the full grinder. Very suspicious :-(

Answer (score 1):

This is how it is intended to work; mobs do not spawn within a 24 block radius from you, so you need to go over 24 blocks away from your farm.

You should not go further than 128 blocks away from it however, as mobs despawn immediately outside of that radius.

[image: Mob spawning]

Comment: That's why I made the spawner 24 blocks high but it's still not working

Comment: @ConstantCanadian It's pretty much irrelevant how tall the roof is; what matters is how far you are away from the spawning spaces. From the images you have given, you are too close to them.

Comment: i thought I could just stand outside of the trap and they would still spawn

Comment: @ConstantCanadian Whether or not you're inside or outside of the trap, you need to be 24 blocks away from the spawning spaces.